# Looking for another expressions of "strike"

Tags: idiom-request

How do you say when some idea(s) or thought(s) arouses some feeling or when you have some certain feeling or thought on something?

Maybe what I'm looking for is rather a literary expression. I searched for it but didn't get what i'm looking for. So I made some expressions on my own and wonder if these make sense.

> This fact comes as a crazy to me.

> This fact comes to me crazy

> This fact comes up to me crazy

If there's any please let me know thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you *specifically* want to describe finding something ***crazy, mad, insane,  nonsensical,...*** OR does "some certain feeling or thought" imply a more *general* "strong reaction" to something you find ***striking, evocative, touching,...*** Note that regardless of that, it's *This fact **strikes me as** [adjective]*, not ***comes to me***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers crazy was just an example. I meant all feelings in general and I think strike me as is what exactly I was looking for thank you very much! could you leave it in the answer section so I can check it as answer, if you don't mind?

Comment: The two comments above are effectively "ephemeral" (they might be deleted by a future "tidying up" process). So you need to *edit your question text* to reflect what they contain, or future visitors to this page won't understand why ***That's really striking**!* is a "better" answer here than ***That's just bonkers**!*

Comment: "That fact **seems** crazy to me"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your suggested expressions are not good English; rather, you could say:

*This/That seems crazy to me.*

but "strikes" seems to be the best option (although I think you excluded that in your title):

*That strikes me as a bit crazy.*

or just (and a bit stronger):

*That's crazy!*

*This is crazy!*

(stronger still):

*That's totally crazy!*